# Why does this circuit give different values for different methods

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

Is there a rule that I am missing?

I need to find the resistance of this circuit:

[image]

I seem to get different values depending on which way I take the resistors. Is there any rule I am missing when analysing these types of circuits to find resistance?

One of my workings is this. But the correct answer is 11.

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Another futile attempt:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your 1st attempt you have one of the legs of the 20R resistor connected to b, which is incorrect. Your 2nd diagram is correct.
In your 2nd attempt on the last line of your calculations you have ... +1/2 = ... but that should be 1/6 as you calculated 6R on the previous line.
After that you still need to add the last 8R resistor, and you're done.

Comment: Still the answer doesn't match, fixing that gives 3 as answer whilst the correct answer is 11. Thanks

Comment: You haven't added the 8R resistor yet ...

Answer (score 2):

These exercise circuits are always drawn in a way designed to confuse the reader.

I would re-draw the circuit like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc5BM1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

so I can see more easily which resistors are in parallel, and which in series.  Then I can solve the thing in small pieces.  I expect the calculations to have "nice" values, and use what may be an unusual way to calculate parallel resistors.

First, R6 (20 Ohm) and R7 (5 Ohm) are in parallel.  You could make 5 Ohms by connecting four 20 Ohms in parallel, so R6 and R7 are effectively 5, 20 Ohm in parallel, which makes 4 Ohms.  With R8 (1 Ohm) in series, this makes 5 Ohms.

R6 - R8 (5 Ohms) are in parallel with another 20 Ohms (R4), so that's 4 Ohms, in series with the 2 Ohm R5, for 6 ohms for everything to the right of R3.

R3 (9 Ohms) could be made with 2, 18 Ohms in parallel, so R2 and R3 are like three 18 Ohms in parallel, which would be 6 Ohms - but that's in parallel with the 6 Ohms to the right, for a net of 3 Ohms.

R1 (8 Ohms) is in series with that, so the grand total is 11 ohms.

Answer (score 0):

you made a mistake in your drawing. What you actually calculate is this:
[image]

Regards MathieuL

Comment: Please see second drawing

Comment: Hi, in your second attempt, you made a mathematical error at your last calculation the answer is 3 than you add 8 + 3 =11 Regards MathieuL

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is correct (aside from the error brhans mentions), but it might be helpful to combine one pair of resistors at a time instead of three at once. That way you can take advantage of a shortcut formula for two parallel resistors:

$$R_{||} = \frac {R_1 R_2} {R_1 + R_2}$$

This is often a lot easier to calculate in your head. For instance, when combining the 20-ohm and 5-ohm resistors, you get:

$$R_{||} = \frac {20 \cdot 5} {20 + 5} = \frac {100} {25} = 4\ \Omega$$

For the 9-ohm and 6-ohm resistors, it's not quite as easy...

$$R_{||} = \frac {9 \cdot 6} {9 + 6} = \frac {54} {15}$$

If you know your multiplication tables and you're comfortable with mental math, you can very quickly tell that the answer is more than three but less than four. (It's exactly 3.6.) That will let you catch any calculation errors. If you're not comfortable with mental math, start practicing! The ability to make quick estimates is always helpful. And in homework and exams, it's easy for one error to spread down the page and ruin a whole problem.

That being said, with a good graphing calculator it's also easy to do this:

$$R_{||} = \frac 1 {\frac {1} {R_1} + \frac {1} {R_2} + \dots + \frac {1} {R_N}} \rightarrow 1/(1/R_1 + 1/R_2 + \dots + 1/R_N)$$